# Numbers not updating on view and On Appearing not helpful

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have method for deleting a word from a dictionary. Deleting works fine and when I debug the method I can see that the correct amount is being transferred to the UI however the UI doesn't update here I can see there is the correct amount

```
AmountOfWordsInDictionary = _allWordsOfUser?.Count ?? default;
```

It updates once I leave and come back. FYI my notify view works fine on any other part of my page, I have also tried on appearing but that is not very helpful

Can you please advise

```
 public int AmountOfWordsInDictionary
 {
       set
       {
            _amountOfWordsInDictionary = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(AmountOfWordsInDictionary));
        }
        get { return _amountOfWordsInDictionary; }
  }
```

**My method:**

```
private async void RemoveWordFromUserDictionary()
{
      if (!wordIsRemoving && !viewDisabled)
      {
            wordIsRemoving = true;
            if (NetworkDelegate.IsOnline)
            {
                 var wordRemovedApiResponse = await App.ApiFactory.RemoveWordFromUserDictionaryAsync(_word, LoggedUser.CurrentUser.Id);
                  if (wordRemovedApiResponse.ApiResponse == ApiResponse.Ok)
                  {
                        FindAnotherWordInDictionary();
                        _allWordsOfUser = App.ApiFactory.GetAllWordsOfUserLocal();
                        AmountOfWordsInDictionary = _allWordsOfUser?.Count ?? default;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NotificationService.ShowToast("something is wrong");
                    }
             }
             else
             {
                    await App.ApiFactory.RemoveWordFromUserDictionaryLocalAsync(_word, LoggedUser.CurrentUser.Id);
                    FindAnotherWordInDictionary();
                    _allWordsOfUser = App.ApiFactory.GetAllWordsOfUserLocal();
                    **AmountOfWordsInDictionary** = _allWordsOfUser?.Count ?? default;
                 **// have also tried _amountOfWordsInDictionary** 
              }
                wordIsRemoving = false;
         }
   }
```

**My xaml :**

```
   <Label
                                       
 Grid.Row="0"
 Grid.Column="1"
 Margin="0"
 FontSize="15"
 HorizontalOptions="End"
 IsVisible="{grial:OnOrientationBool Default='true',
                                                                            LandscapePhone='false'}"
 Text="{Binding AmountOfWordsInDictionary,Mode=TwoWay}"
 TextColor="{DynamicResource CircleActionButtonFlatTextColor}"
 VerticalOptions="Start" />

 public Dictionary()
     {
       InitializeComponent();
       BindingContext = new DictionaryViewModel();
     }
```

Comment: does your VM implement INotifyPropertyChanged?  Also, there is no point in using TwoWay binding for a Label

Comment: Ah ok, yes. it does and that woks fine on other properties